# Spark 2.2: Load org.apache.spark.ml.feature.LabeledPoint from file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-2.0

The following line of code loads the (soon to be deprecated) `mllib.regression.LabeledPoint` from file to an `RDD[LabeledPoint]`:

```
MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(spark.sparkContext, s"$path${File.separator}${fileName}_data_sparse").repartition(defaultPartitionSize)
```

I'm unable to find the equivalent function for `ml.feature.LabeledPoint`, which is not yet heavily used in the Spark documentation examples.

Can someone point me to the relevant function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `ml` package you won't need to put the data into a `LabeledPoint` since you can specify which columns to use for labels/features in all transformations/algorithms. For example:

```
val gbt = new GBTClassifier()
  .setLabelCol("label")
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
```

---

To load the `LibSVM` file as a dataframe, simply do:

```
val df = spark.read.format("libsvm").load(s"$path${File.separator}${fileName}_data_sparse")
```

Which will return a dataframe with two columns:

> The loaded DataFrame has two columns: label containing labels stored as doubles and features containing feature vectors stored as Vectors.

See the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/source/libsvm/LibSVMDataSource.html) for more information.